# How to calculate the tax for US stock trading?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks

Assume I have $200 and I bought stock A and stock B $100 each

Stock A, I earn 10 dollars.
Stock B, I lose 10 dollars.

How much do I need to pay for US government?
Is it the net earning = 0, so I don't need to pay tax.
OR
I need to pay tax for the 10 dollars that I earn? If that is the case, how to take care the $10 that I lose?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this occurs in the same year, your net for the year is zero. It's reported, but zeroes out to no taxable event.